# C++, free debug tool for watching threads in windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Trying to understand, why my C++/Qt application creates 18 threads, while i don't create more than 4, considering main() as 5th thread, where Qt's event loop is executing.

OS: Win7-32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the OS is windows: you can use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) (click on the process, threads, and you can check the call stack for each thread).

Also, if you are using visual studio, you can switch between threads or see them all in the "Parallel Stacks" (attach to a process, Debug->Windows->Parallel stacks).

Comment: Thank you! ProcesExplorer is cute :) Second advice (Parallel Stacks) took empty window to me (successfully attached, opened Debug->Windows->Parallel stacks, got empty window).